# How to check which ViewController is used in sub Class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a shooting game which has 2 game mode (redMode and blueMode). These 2 modes are ViewController, have subView(UIView sub class) and game result view that shows how much you got a score.
But there are some differences depends on game mode. I tried to make "ResultView Class" and want to let these 2 game mode have the class. But I don't know how to separate processing depends on game mode.

Ideal:

1. Make "ResultView Class"
2. Make ResultView in each game mode (RedView and BlueView) in the function "showResultView"
3. separate some processing depends on game mode

(Now I make "resultView" in each game mode even the contents are almost same")

How can I solve it?

```
//ViewController for RedMode
class RedGameViewController: UIViewController {

var gameStatus: status!
var redView: RedView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    redView = RedView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 568))
    self.view.addSubview(redView)
    redView.redGameViewController = self
    //.....
    }

enum status: String {
    case isPlaying = "isPlaying"
    case isPausing = "isPausing"
    case isGameOver = "isGameOver"
    }

class RedView: UIView {

    weak var redGameViewController: RedGameViewController!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
     super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    //....
    @objc func showResultView(){ 
        var resultView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 568))
        resultView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        resultView.image = UIImage(named:"resultView_BG")!
        self.addSubview(resultView)

        resultScoreLabel.text = String(score)
        resultBackToTopBtn.isHidden = false
        if redViewController.gameStatus == .isGameOver {
            print("isGameOver")
        }else{
            print("Clear")
        }
    }
}
//ViewController for BlueMode
class BlueGameViewController: UIViewController {

var gameStatus: status!
var blueView: BlueView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    blueView = BlueView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 568))
    self.view.addSubview(blueView)
    blueView.blueGameViewController = self
    //.....
    }
enum status: String {
    case isPlaying = "isPlaying"
    case isPausing = "isPausing"
    case isGameOver = "isGameOver"
    }

class BlueView: UIView {

    weak var blueGameViewController: BlueGameViewController!
    override init(frame: CGRect) {

    super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    //....
    @objc func showResultView(){ 
        var resultView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 568))
        resultView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        resultView.image = UIImage(named:"resultView_BG")!
        self.addSubview(resultView)

        //Different from showResultView in RedView
        resultScoreLabel.text = String(score*10)
        resultBackToTopBtn.isHidden = true
        if blueViewController.gameStatus == .pausing {
            print("isPausing")
        }else{
            print("Clear")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great way to do that would be the use of Protocol.

**Option 1:**

Let say you have a protocol named ColoredView that contains your logic method

```
protocol ColoredView {
     func showResult(/* add parameters if you need them */)
}
```

Inside your UIViewController named ResultViewController, you would have a ColoredView capable of calling your logic function like

```
class ResultViewController {
     var coloredView: UIView!

     func showResultView() {
          guard let coloredView = self.coloredView as? ColoredView else {
              // This is not a coloredView
              return
          }
          coloredView.showResult()
     }
}
```

From that, just create your two views that implement your protocol

```
class RedView: UIView, ColoredView {
    func showResult() {
        // Insert Red logic here
    }
}

class BlueView: UIView, ColoredView {
    func showResult() {
        // Insert Blue logic here
    }
}
```

And then just create your ResultViewController with RedView or BlueView as its coloredView.

**Option 2:**

You can just separate your variables using a protocol like

```
protocol ColoredView {
     func getScoreText(from score: Int) -> String
     func getPrintText(for status: Status) -> String
     var isHidden: Bool
}
```

And just as option 1

```
func showResult() {
    if let coloredView = self.coloredView as? ColoredView {
        resultScoreLabel.text = coloredView.getScoreText(from: score)
        resultBackToTopBtn.isHidden = coloredView.isHidden
        print(coloredView.getPrintText(for: gameStatus)
    }
}
```

With

```
class RedView: UIView, ColoredView {
     func getScoreText(from score: Int) -> String {
         // Insert Red logic here
    }

    var isHidden = false

    func getPrintText(for status: Status) -> String {
         // Insert Red logic here
    }
}

class BlueView: UIView, ColoredView {
     func getScoreText(from score: Int) -> String {
         // Insert Blue logic here
    }

    var isHidden = true

    func getPrintText(for status: Status) -> String {
         // Insert Blue logic here
    }
}
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I want to ask you, where can I add views in common like background image of ResultViewController and buttons?

Comment: Since it's a generic solution, you could add those views right inside the ResultViewController. Either you are using storyboards and you can "duplicate" your viewController or you can instantiate a default ResultViewController and then add your coloredView programmatically. An other option is to set up subClasses of ResultViewController like a ResultRedViewController and a ResultBlueViewController, set all the default logic in the superClass and then implement the rest in your subControllers.
I would personally build a ResultViewController and instantiate my coloredView programmatically.